# adding a custom function to a model in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a users table that has location attributes and would like to create a model function that retrieves nearby users (within a given radius).  Here is my model:

```
    class User extends AppModel {
        public function getNearbyUsers($id,$dist=10) {
            return $this->query(...);
        }
    }
```

And here is my controller where I am trying to invoke the function:

```
    class UsersController extends AppController {
        public function getNearbyUsers($id) {
            ...
            $this->User->getNearbyUsers($id)
            ...
        }
    }
```

However doing so results in: `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getNearbyUsers() on a non-object`

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: nevermind, it is not complaining about that anymore.  But it is throwing an SQL error and my model function is never actually being called.  Upon further inspection on the mysql query log I see this:

```
    Query   SHOW TABLES FROM `xxx`
    Query   getNearbyUsers
    Quit
```

Seems CakePHP is interpreting $this->User->getNearbyUsers as a literal query. So my question still remains: how to add custom functions to a model in Cake?

Comment: The code looks correct. Did you clean the cache in `app/tmp/cache`?

Comment: I have the same problem it was not available till cakePHP 1.3 it come with CakePHP 2.4.x (at least I test).

Comment: where you able to solve the query issue. I am facing same\

Comment: @aWebDeveloper: You should have a look at my fresh answer, this solved my query issue with custom metods in models, using Cake v1.3.

Answer (score 4):

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/additional-methods-and-properties.html:

> While CakePHP’s model functions should get you where you need to go,
>   don’t forget that model classes are just that: classes that allow you
>   to write your own methods or define your own properties.
>
> Any operation that handles the saving and fetching of data is best
>   housed in your model classes. This concept is often referred to as the
>   fat model.

Model

```
class Example extends AppModel {
    function getRecent() {
        $conditions = array(
            'created BETWEEN (curdate() - interval 7 day) and (curdate() - interval 0 day)'
        );

        return $this->find('all', compact('conditions'));
    }
}
```

> This **getRecent()** method can now be used within the controller.

Controller

```
$recent = $this->Example->getRecent();
```

Comment: As you can see from the code I included I am pretty much following exactly what you posted :)

Comment: The doc entry is invalid now (maybe is was deleted) because the link just redirects to models documentation, where there is no mention about additional methods.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few additional items that needs to be in the code, or else you will get the non-object error.

In the App Model :

```
<?php

class Get extends AppModel {
    public function getRecent() {
        // $conditions = array(
            // 'created BETWEEN (curdate() - interval 7 day)' .
            // ' and (curdate() - interval 0 day))'
        // );
        // return $this->find('all', compact('conditions'));
    }
}
```

In the app controller,

```
?php



class GetsController extends AppController {

    public $uses = array('Get');  // Needed, or the error will appear.

    public function Example () {
       $this->Get->getRecent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with Cake 1.3, using Plugins (Modules), and even if we had the model name unique in the whole app *(some model names are used in more then one plugin)* it only worked once I requested the Model in the controller's `$uses` array with it's plugin to, like this: `'Module1.A'`

app/plugins/plugin1/controllers/a_controller.php:

```
class AController extends AppController {

    // using simple array('A') worked fine for cake methods (find, query ...)
    // but did not recognized the custom method
    public $uses = array('Plugin1.A');

    public function Example () {
       $this->A->customMethod();
    }
}
```

app/plugins/plugin1/models/a.php:

```
<?php

class A extends AppModel {
    public function customMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}
```